# Vue - tweening a component which is not created

Tags: vue.js, gsap, vue-reactivity, vue-dynamic-components

I have a dynamic component which renders based on a json object.

```
 <template v-for="(vehicle, index) in vehicles">
 <component
    :class="`item${index}`"
    :is="vehicle.type"

  />
```

Where vehicle type is a component which can either be car, motorbike or lorry. Essentially, this is what should be rendered.

```
<car />
<motorbike />
<lorry />
```

The issue I am having is because these are dynamic components they do not tween using either css classes or vue `$refs`.

```
  this.$forceUpdate();
  TweenMax.fromTo(this.$refs.item[0], 2, {
        opacity: 0,
        x: -300,
        ease: Power2.easeIn,

      }, {
        opacity: 1,
        x: 0,
        delay: 1
      });
```

I have tried using `$nextick()` and `$forceUpdate()`; but the tween does not trigger. It looks like one of the reactivity caveats. In the old jquery days I think defer would have fixed it.

Is there a work around to make dynamic components available via the `$refs`?

The tween engine used is [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap/).

Comment: you can try to signal an event in the `mounted` hook of your components, and call the tween when the event is triggered. In this case `$refs` should work

Comment: yes I that does work but the problem is I need to stagger tween them so the tween needs to be on the parent. I suppose I could emit an 'I'm available' event and still do the tween in the parent.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, emit an event. The tween will remain within the parent component